# Checking a MenuItem in a BottomNavigatorBar in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem, bottomnavigationview

I want in my app a button that when pressed sucessfully navigates as if the user had pressed the second available button that is the BottomNavigatorBar.

I've mostly achieved the desired behavior by defining an static function which when called from another fragment if mostly imitates the sam behavior that would happen if the user had pressed that button:

That's its code:

```
  companion object
    {
        […]
        fun calledFun(it: MenuItem, binding: FragmentContainerBinding) {
            when (it.itemId) {

            R.id.nav_assets -> binding.vpPrivate.currentItem = 0
            R.id.nav_incidents -> binding.vpPrivate.currentItem = 1
            R.id.nav_profile -> binding.vpPrivate.currentItem = 2



        }

        it.isChecked=true

    }
}
```

But unluckily the it.isChecked, that I think should put the corresponding MenuItem to red color, doesn't work, it keeps showing on the same MenuItem that was selected when the button I first mention has been pressed.

It has been checked, that despite that, it's really showing what should show with that MenuItem. Indeed, if I press the MenuItem with red color, content changes to the one it were.

How can I mark that MenuItem as if the user had selected it?

Comment: Do you need only to mark the item or also run the function (like the user pressed on it). It was not clear for me what do you want to accomplish

Comment: @DemoDemo Function (showing the corresponding fragment) is already done with the binding.vpPrivate.item asignation that changes a NonSwipeableViewPage), I'd just need to mark the menuItem as checked.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to achieve just selecting an item in the navbar you can do something like this

```
testing.setOnClickListener {
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(null)
        navView.menu.getItem(0).isChecked = true
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }
```

It's similar in a way when you are working with checkbox's/radiobuttons but you don't want to trigger the functionality when you change the selected state.